# Detail regarding $state.go() functionality

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When doing

`$state.go('search', {param: value});`

shouldn't the `go` method update the query parameters to `?param=value` in the url just like

`$location.search({param: value});`

would ?

Answer (score 0):

If your state definition has a url with the parameter in it, then yes.

```
.state({ name: 'search', url: '/search?param' })
```